# Does openJump or Jump support the embedding of videos or images?

Tags: java, openjump, video

I've been tasked with writing a plugin for openJump.

The idea is that you have some points/markers and when you click on them a video/image is presented (whether in a dialog, web browser, etc.)

I've been looking for other plugins, or even info on the subject, and I'm beginning to think that is not possible.

Can anyone provide further information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in OpenJUMP yet. There is a partial support for showing static images through map tooltips which is somehow explained in the comments of this open feature request https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/feature-requests/80/. Kosmo GIS http://opengis.es has a hyperlink function and because Kosmo is based on OpenJUMP you might find some reusable code for your plugin from the source code of Kosmo.